# How to create 10k records in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe in pandas but there is only 1 value stored in it. Is there a way in Pandas to fill the dataframe with 10k records?
Here's the dataframe that I've created.

```
from mimesis import Cryptographic
import pandas as pd
c= Cryptographic()
string = 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/'
profile_url = string + "/" + c.token_urlsafe()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Profile_Url':[profile_url]})
print(df1.head())
```

and this is the result after printing it.

```
 Picture_URL
0  https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/_YIp1UQhJFAyIxSn0eWvb...
```

I want to store these unique urls 10000times unlike repeating the same record for 10000times

so I am expecting something like..

```
Picture_URL
0  https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/_YIp1UQhKFMyIxSn0eWvn...
0  https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/_KIy1UQhEFAyIxSn0eWvt...
0  https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/_WIp1UQhSFAyIxSx0eWzq...
```

how can I add rows upto 10K

Comment: `pd.concat([df]*1000)` ?

Comment: @Datanovice its only giving a single value and not 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list` comprehension for generate `10000` different links in list comprehension:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Profile_Url':[string + "/" + c.token_urlsafe() for i in range(10000)]})
```